# Using PayPal Core SDK with .Net not receiving payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

We are setup to use the REST APIs using the PayPal Core SDK in .Net.

Moving from the SANDBOX to the LIVE environment, we're using the clientID and clientSecret provided in the LIVE tab.

It correctly shows the PayPal account that we expect to receive funds and we also get LIVE transactions shown in the developer console clicking on a transaction we get the transaction details the following is a snippet of a response showing LIVE PayPal URLs.

```
{
    "status": 201,
    "duration_time": 403,
    "body": {
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "[url]api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-2UM007466X5580429KYMULWY",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "self"
            },
            {
                "href": "[url]www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd\\u003d_express-checkout\\u0026token\\u003dEC-13U694454H027590M",
                "method": "REDIRECT",
                "rel": "approval_url"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-2UM007466X5580429KYMULWY/execute",
                "method": "POST",
                "rel": "execute"
            }
        ],
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        }
```

The issue is that funds aren't hitting the LIVE PayPal account and no notifications are being sent to either the payer or payee.  How do we determine if funds are being received and if they are, where they are being directed to.

Please note I've put [url] as a placeholder for https:// so that this question can be posted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.  The resolution was that the LIVE transactions only represented payment approvals and not payment executions and therefore funds would not have been transferred and no notifications sent.